# Dirichlet distribution parameters from known variances

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, optimization, dirichlet-distribution

Let's assume, I know the variances of Dirichlet distribution parameters. Let these variances be:
$Var[X_1], ..., Var[X_n]$.

Is there a analytical solution to derive the parameter value alpha_i given the variances $Var[X_1], ..., Var[X_n]$.

The variance for $X_i$ is defined in e.g. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), but somehow I am not able to derive $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ given the variances $Var[X_1], ..., Var[X_n]$.

This has to be a very simple problem to solve, please help me. :)

Comment: I think there may be two solutions when $n=2$ (as the two variances will clearly be equal) and it would not surprise me if something similar happened with larger $n$

Comment: @Henry, how so? There are exactly n equations and n alphas to be solved. I understand that if this was some kind of nth degree polynomial equation, then this would be the case. However, I am not spotting anything like that here. And what do you mean that the two variances are equal? They are if the alphas are equal, but not otherwise.

Comment: When $n=2$ you have $X_2=1-X_1$ so $\mathrm{Var}(X_2)=\mathrm{Var}(X_1)$.  This is equal to $\frac{a_1a_2}{(a_1+a_2)^2(a_1+a_2+1)}$ meaning you have one equation and two unknowns

Comment: When the number of algebraic equations equals the number of variables, and those equations are not redundant, all you can say generally is that there will be a *finite* number of solutions--not that there is a unique one.  The most basic example of this is the quadratic equation in one variable, with its well known formula for up to *two* solutions.  In the present case there will be up to two solutions for *each marginal variable,* as you can (easily) work out from the formula for the variance in terms of the parameter.

Comment: Some experimentation suggests that with $n=2$ there are usually an infinite number of solutions if there are any, while with $n>2$ every example I tried with a goal seeker came up with a single solution with each $a_i>0$ or no such solution (not that that is a proof - I may have been looking for solutions in the wrong places)

Comment: Since beta distribution is a special case of Dirichlet distribution (i = 2), and the parameters (called alpha and beta, while they could as well be called alpha_1 and alpha_2 as well) can be solved:
alpha = ((1 - E(X_1)) / VAR(X_1) - 1 / E(X_1)) * E(X_1) ^ 2
beta = alpha * (1 / E(X_1) - 1)

I was wondering: If expected values AND variances were all known for all the Dirichlet distribution parameters, could all the alphas be solved then?

So the expected values are needed to get a unique solutions for every alpha?